# Getting circular dependency error while creating calculated column

Tags: dax

I have a measure in my Sales table :

```
WW_Anchor_R6Sales :=
VAR R6Sales =
    CALCULATE (
        [MeasureR6Sales] > 0,
        FILTER ( Product, Product[Program] = "WW" && Product[Anchor] = "Y" )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( R6Sales ), 0, R6Sales )
```

```
LY_Anchor_R6Sales :=
VAR R6Sales =
    CALCULATE (
        [MeasureR6Sales] > 0,
        FILTER ( Product, Product[Program] = "LY" && Product[Anchor] = "Y" )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( R6Sales ), 0, R6Sales )
```

```
MeasureR6Sales :=
VAR salesR6 =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Sales[SalesAmount] ),
        FILTER (
            Sales,
            Sales[InvoiceDate] >= EDATE ( [LastClosedMonth], -5 )
                && Sales[InvoiceDate] <= [LastClosedMonth]
                && Sales[SalesAmount] > 0
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( salesR6 ), 0, salesR6 )
```

When I have created a calculated column:

```
WW_Anchor_R6 := IF ( [WW_Anchor_R6Sales] > 0, "Yes", "No" )
```

I am able to create, but when I am trying to create another calculated column say:

```
CalculatedColumn1 := IF ( [LY_Anchor_R6Sales] > 0, "Yes", "No" )
```

it is giving me an error saying that

> Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'A circular dependency was detected: Sales[Calculated Column 1], Sales[WW_Anchor_R6], Sales[Calculated Column 1].

How to fix this error?

Comment: Classic case of calculated column circular dependency: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/avoiding-circular-dependency-errors-in-dax/

Comment: @AlexisOlson
I have checked this video, but still, I am not able to fix my code.